# Dynamic Checkboxlist in repeater, ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater, checkboxlist

I have a `CheckBoxList` in a `Repeater` and the code I have is from here [Dynamic dropdownlist in repeater, ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6560114/dynamic-dropdownlist-in-repeater-asp-net).

If do this:

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="chklWorkType" runat="server" OnDataBinding="chklWorkType_DataBinding"></asp:CheckBoxList>


protected void chklWorkType_DataBinding(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBoxList chk = (CheckBoxList)(sender);

    chk.Items.Add(new ListItem("nem 1", "1"));
    chk.Items.Add(new ListItem("num 2", "2"));

    chk.SelectedValue = chk.DataValueField;
}
```

**This is my error message:**

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'chklWorkType' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`DataValueField`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.datavaluefield(v=vs.110).aspx) gets or sets the field of the data source that provides the value of each list item. So normally the name of a column or something like that. But you are using this name as [`SelectedValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) which  doesn't exist because you haven't assingned one, so it's `String.Empty`.

You could use this, if you want the first item to be selected:

```
chk.SelectedValue = "1";
```

That's the value of the first `ListItem`(`new ListItem("nem 1", "1")`).

Of course you could also use the [`SelectedIndex`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedindex(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
chk.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks , I understand what you mean. Error fixed.