# How can I use checkbox list in repeater?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to use checkbox list in repeater at asp.net, C#.
But NO "CHOICES_CONTENT" comes up on web page..
Here's my code.

```
<asp:Repeater id="Repeater0"runat="server"DataSource='<%#GetChild(Container.DataItem,"ChoicesRelate") %>'> 
    <ItemTemplate>  
        <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkBoxListGoup" runat="server"  
            DataTextField="CHOICES_CONTENT" 
            DataValueField="CHOICES_CONTENT">
        </asp:CheckBoxList>
    </ItemTemplate>                                
 </asp:Repeater>
```

Where should I modify?

### EDITED

I've changed my code a little bit.

```
<asp:Repeater id="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSource='<%# GetChild(Container.DataItem,"ChoicesRelate") %>'>  
    <ItemTemplate>  
        <asp:RadioButtonList id="RadioButtonList1" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem Value="">  CHOICES_NO </asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="CHOICES_ID" Text='<%# Eval("QUESTION_CONTENT") %>'>    </asp:ListItem>         
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Next problem is that I can't use Eval("QUESTION_CONTENT") in asp tag.
How can I pick up "QUESTION_CONTENT" data??

Comment: this seems fine, what seems the problem?

Comment: NO "CHOICES_CONTENT" comes up on web page..

Comment: @G.G.Sato - i guess you can't populate the check box list, is it?

Comment: You can go for dynamic checkbox list in repeater ,
Following Following link :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35064939/dynamic-checkboxlist-in-repeater-asp-net

Comment: What is data type of CHOICES_CONTENT? You need to bind to chkbox list.

Comment: @Spider - exactly

Comment: @UJS - thanks!! I reat that page, but I still cant solve problem,,

Comment: @Mike - data type means like object, int ,,,etc?

Comment: Yes. Anyway..please see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use repeater OnItemDataBound event.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptTest" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptTest_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBoxList ID="ChkBoxList" runat="server">
        </asp:CheckBoxList>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>

protected void rptTest_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType.Equals(ListItemType.AlternatingItem) || e.Item.ItemType.Equals(ListItemType.Item))
        {
            CheckBoxList cboxlist = e.Item.FindControl("chChkBoxListk") as CheckBoxList;

            cboxlist.DataSource = "Datasource for checkbox list (datatable, object list and so on..)";
            cboxlist.DataTextField = "TextDisplayField";
            cboxlist.DataValueField = "ValueField";
            cboxlist.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

Comment: ThankS!!  I could solve this problem , I thought for long time!!

Comment: Please mark as Answer if your problem resolved! Thanks.